# How to create a view that CROSS APPLYs a series of inline table-valued UDFs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2017

Here's the code structure I'm looking at:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]

    AS SELECT t1.[ID]        ,
              udf1.[Column1] ,
              udf1.[Column2] ,
              udf1.[Column3]

        FROM [Table1] t1
            CROSS APPLY [dbo].[UDF1] ( [dbo].[UDF2] ( t1.[ID] ) ) udf1

GO
```

`[dbo].[UDF1]` and `[dbo].[UDF2]` are both inline table valued functions.

I don't remember the exact details, but SSMS gave me errors when I tried to use `JOIN`, and SO told me I needed to use `CROSS APPLY` to fix it - I think that was the right choice though?

Anyway, the main issue I have right now is:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.UDF2", or the name is ambiguous.

... despite the fact that `UDF2` clearly exists: I can see it in SSMS.

I suspect the real problem is the way `UDF2` is passed as a parameter into `UDF1`.
`UDF2` returns a table, and the columns exactly match the table-valued parameter defined for `UDF1`.

But I *think* SQL Server doesn't support this syntax?
Do I need to convert my view into a multi-line table-valued function, declare a table variable to receive the results of `UDF2`, and then pass that table variable into `UDF1`?

(P.S. SQL Server's errors are some of the least helpful I've ever seen, in any language ...)

Comment: Yikes thats going to perform terribly.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Is there a better performing alternative? I guess I thought inline functions performed pretty well in this context ... but I don't really understand `CROSS APPLY`, so ...

Comment: Don't use UDFs.

Comment: @ErikPhilips (Also, I feel like I should mention, this is operating on in-memory OLTP data, not the hard disk. So performance won't be _quite_ as bad as it looks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably have really poor performance, but I think you need to use a separate  CROSS APPLY for each table-value function. I don't think it is possible to use the contents returned by UDF2 in UDF1, since UDF1 would need a parameter of Table Type and UDF2 returns a Table but not a Table Type.

Functions cannot return Table Types, so you will probably have to find another solution. You could create yet another function that inserts the results of UDF2 into a Table Type and then calls UDF1.

If you could do it, it would look something like:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
    AS SELECT t1.[ID]        ,
              udf1.[Column1] ,
              udf1.[Column2] ,
              udf1.[Column3]
        FROM [Table1] t1
            CROSS APPLY [dbo].[UDF2] ( t1.[ID] ) udf2
            CROSS APPLY [dbo].[UDF1] ( udf2 ) udf1
GO
```

To create "yet another wrapper function" it would look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF3](
    @id INT -- data type for t1.ID
) RETURNS @t TABLE (
    -- ... Your columns here ...
) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your user defined Table Type
    DECLARE @udf2 UDF2_TABLE 
    INSERT @udf2 (... columns ...)
    SELECT udf2.* -- try to use exact column names instead of *
      FROM [Table1] t1
         CROSS APPLY [dbo].[UDF2]( t1.[ID] )

    -- I'm not really sure this is possible either
    INSERT @t (... columns ...)
    SELECT udf1.*
      FROM [dbo].[UDF1](@udf2) udf1

    RETURN;
END
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Cool. (Also, I feel like I should mention, this is operating on in-memory OLTP data, not the hard disk. So performance won't be _quite_ as bad as it looks.)